# Offline comparison of two arrays iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, compare, push-notification, offlineapps

I have two arrays containing string variables. In one array, it contains the values from a web service, it will be updating in every 5 seconds. So, i need to run this app offline and also compare the array with another array that contains some sample values. If any matches occur, should generate a PushNotification. Is that possible?? If yes how can I implement that? If no, is there any other way?

Please help...
Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Hey I can just give you an idea.

register your app for background app

 in did enter background make a background handler and you will get approximately 10 mins to finish the task, after the time is over the handler will call finishing block and in this block again create the background handler you will get again 10 mins and so on, in this way your application will reamin in background. But be aware of watchdog. 
P.S. This is just an idea, i dont know the apple's view on this. Hope you will succeed.

Comment: I seriously like your idea but is there any how you can verify this .. i mean if apple will accept this. Post it as a question..

Comment: I don't know whether apple accept this idea or not.... I suggest you to upload a sample app on app store or just ask apple's support.

Comment: I was going through the documents and found out  that the setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:

Comment: I was going through the docs and found out that setKeepAliveTimeout:handler: works only for VoIP apps so I guess it rules out the possibility of performing this task.